# Facebook authentication in a new browser instance Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I have an Asp.Net MVC 4 app an i have a feature in which the app can post to user's wall.
Its working fine, but currently the url

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:xxxxxx/&scope=publish_stream

redirects to facebook page , authenticates ,post the message and redirects back to my app.

Is it possible to open the facebook authentication page in a new browser instance and somehow close the browser instance once the message is posted ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this covers what you want to achieve but by using [Facebook Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), you can set [`display`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display) parameter to appropriate value (e.g. popup) and let the user publish a story to a timeline.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try and let you know !

Comment: Would be nice if you someone can send me a link to a sample.

Comment: in the facebook feed dialog sample (link provided in my answer), in `Direct Url` section, it says "Click here to try the url yourself". click on the link to see a sample